# Issue on compiling config.guess from llvm project source with cmake on cygwin

Tags: command-line, cygwin, cmake, llvm

It seems like my compiler is not adapted to the syntax on the file `config.guess` and it keeps getting errors. The URL from which I downloaded the source is [llvm project](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libunwind/trunk) or more specifically [problematic source file](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/cmake/config.guess), svn command `svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk llvm`

\r seems to mean new line

I also had problems with some blank lines, then just commenting them solved it but that issue on line 71 persisted. It seems like on the line there is a positional parameter not being compiled: $1

> /home/computador/gsrc/independent/llvm/cmake/config.guess: linha 71: erro de sintaxe próximo ao token inesperado `$'in\r''
>   /home/computador/gsrc/independent/llvm/cmake/config.guess: linha 71:`  case $1 'n
>   CMake Error at cmake/modules/GetHostTriple.cmake:27 (message):
>     Failed to execute /home/computador/gsrc/independent/llvm/cmake/config.guess
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     cmake/config-ix.cmake:380 (get_host_triple)
>     CMakeLists.txt:611 (include)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   See also "/home/computador/gsrc/independent/llvm_build/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>   See also "/home/computador/gsrc/independent/llvm_build/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

The block I am having problems with:

```
while test $# -gt 0 ; do
case $1 in
--time-stamp | --time* | -t )
   echo "$timestamp" ; exit ;;
--version | -v )
   echo "$version" ; exit ;;
--help | --h* | -h )
   echo "$usage"; exit ;;
-- )     # Stop option processing
   shift; break ;;
- ) # Use stdin as input.
   break ;;
-* )
   echo "$me: invalid option $1$help" >&2
   exit 1 ;;
* )
   break ;;
esac
done
```

How can I edit this code so that I can compile it on my machine?
my cmake generator is unix makefiles

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and it turns out it was because of some DOS line endings in the config.guess file.

I resolved it by replacing them with unix line endings:

```bsh
dos2unix path/to/config.guess
```

Answer (score 0):

getting the code from git resolved the issue, they have the last revisions there, actually they say that downloading from svn is deprecated on [getting started documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-with-llvm). Also I followed the instructions on [installing clang](https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) and made the build folder inside the source one. Now it is compilling without error. I got informations from an unofficial page but did not knew about the migration they were doing to git